# Deletar Chave Regedit Windows

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um **programa em C#** para automatizar uma situação aqui na empresa, só que estou enfrentando problemas com isso

Estou querendo deletar uma chave do registro do windows fica localizada em HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing

No caso eu gostaria de deletar a chave **MSLicensing** ou deletar tudo que se encontra dentro dela.

Estou usando o seguinte comando

```
string caminho = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing";
Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey(caminho, true);
```

Estou executando o VS como administrador já coloquei um manifest com nivel elevado e mesmo assim nada de conseguir deletar.

Obrigado pela atenção de todos.

Comment: Acho que ao invés do `Registry` seria a `RegistryKey` do  `Microsoft.Win32`... Mas porque você está querendo fazer isso? MSLicensing é só um exemplo e você pretende apagar o registro de um software seu mesmo?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na documentação da Microsoft (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys). Pode ser problema de redirecionamento de chave, já tive problemas desse tipo.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, adicione essa referência:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

E para deletar use esse trecho:

```
string keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing";
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true);
key.DeleteValue("ValorASerDeletado");
```

Comment: Olá.
Usei o comando que você passou e esta me retornando o seguinte erro
Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

o meu código esta da seguinte maneira.

string keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing\Store\LICENSE000";
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName, true);
key.DeleteValue("ClientLicense");

Comment: A Key está ficando nula por algum motivo. Faça uma validação se Key é nula e avalie se o registro que está tentando apagar existe e é válido.